# Getting an array for user ids from an array of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the amistad gem to handle friend relationships. Users have events associated with them. I would like to provide a feed of events for the a given user based on who they are friends with.

I have used the following code from http://ruby.railstutorial.org for follow relationships. However with amistad i don't have a **user.friend_ids** method only a **user.friends** method.

How can I get a similar feed type of result (that can be paged and all that) with the **user.friends** call that gives me a list of user objects and not just the ids?

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'

  # Return microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  private

    # Return an SQL condition for users followed by the given user.
    # We include the user's own id as well.
    def self.followed_by(user)
      following_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                        WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
      where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
            { :user_id => user })
    end
end
```

This is mostly pseudocode as it doesn't work, but here's what I *think* I'm trying to accomplish in code:

```
class Event< ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope :order => 'event.created_at DESC'

  # Return events from friends of a user.
  scope :from_friends, lambda { |user| friends_of(user) }

  private

    # Return an SQL condition for users followed by the given user.
    # We include the user's own id as well.
    def self.friends_of(user)
      friend_ids = %(SELECT friendIDs FROM friendships)
      where("user_id IN (#{friend_ids})")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add `friend_ids` method to the `User` model.

```
def friend_ids
  self.friends.map(&:id)
  //Here, I'm iterating over user.friends array and getting an array of ids
end
```

**EDIT**: As per your comment, I'm assuming you have the associations between user and events built up properly.
e.g A user has many events and an event belongs to a user/multiple users (depending on your requirements.)

Once you have the associations setup correctly, you can simply lookout for events with the `user_ids` which you got from above `friend_ids` method.

Comment: What does self.friends.map(&:id) do? Would there be a way to do this as a subselect as it is above - wouldn't this make it able to be paged? Thanks!

Comment: self.friends.map(&:id) is shorthand for self.friends.map{|friend| friend.id}. This will fetch all columns, not just the id. Can you describe the database schemas of the tables you are using?

Comment: @Rapture: I re-read your question and found in the last line that " You want a similar feed with user.friends that gives you the objects and not just the ids".
Well That's what you actually get with user.friends
I'm not getting as to what your problem is, except the paging part.

Comment: I'm very new to rails and activerecord mind you - so I might have misstated things. I don't know how to take my array of users from users.friends and tell activerecord - "I want all the events that these users have created."